# Verify if cell exists in array of cells

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to iterate through a spreadsheet column while skipping the duplicated values. To do so, I use TextFinder to get all the cells with identical values and I add them to a "duplicates" array.

At every iteration, an *if* clause verifies if the current cell is part of the "duplicates" array and if so, it should just skip to the next iteration. However, it isn't the case; it proceeds through my *if* clause. I tried both "includes()" and "indexOf()".

Here's my code:

```
let duplicates = [];
    for (let row = 1; row <= range.getNumRows(); row++) {
      const cell = range.getCell(row, 1);
      const value = cell.getValue();

      if (duplicates.includes(cell) == false) {
        let array = range.createTextFinder(value).findAll();
        const cellIndex = array.indexOf(cell);
        array.splice(cellIndex, 1);
        duplicates.push(...array);
      }
    }
```

I'm honestly not sure why it doesn't work. However, I'm new to coding and it's probably a beginner's mistake.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: From a quick glance, you are not checking if `cellIndex` is negative, so next line will remove one item from array regardless.  [Array.prototype.splice(): If start is negative, it will begin that many elements from the end of the array.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: `Cell` is a `Range` object. Only primitive values - strings/numbers can be compared. `Cell` cannot be compared. Compare their values instead.

Comment: Not very clear on your desired output. Could you share a picture of your before and desired output? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're only trying to find the unique values of a column, try:

```
function uniqueValuesOfColumn() {

  return [...new Set(
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                  .getSheetByName(`Sheet1`)
                  .getRange(`A:A`)
                  .getValues()
                  .flat()
                  .filter(Boolean)
  )]

  /* Or

  const uniqueValues = [...new Set(
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                  .getSheetByName(`Sheet1`)
                  .getRange(`A:A`)
                  .getValues()
                  .flat()
                  .filter(Boolean)
  )];

  */

}
```

This converts all values of a column, with empty cells removed, into an array of unique values. This is done by 'converting' a `Set` of values into an array.

- [Set - JavaScript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)